# Jooq query results how to automatically map to pojo？

Tags: jooq

this is pojo User:

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    private UInteger      id;
    private String        openId;
...
}
```

this is pojo UserDTO:

```
public class UserDTO extends User implements Serializable{

    @JsonProperty("sk")
    private String sk;

    @JsonProperty("cars")
    private List<Car> cars; //There are user id in table car
...
}
```

jooq query is as follows：

```
    UserDTO userDTO  = dslContext.select().from(User.USER).
leftJoin(Car.CAR).on(User.USER.ID.eq(Car.CAR.USER_ID))
    .where(User.USER.OPEN_ID.eq(openId)).fetchOneInto(UserDTO.class);
```

I see the UserDTO's cars is null.
I would like to use jooq query results automatically fill into the UserDTO car instead of manually traversing the query results and then assigned to the car. How can I do?

I tried to use the third-party mapper, the problem is the result of the query Some fields are null, this will result in mapper conversion exception, the exception is as follows:

```
    "Exception in thread" main "java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    At java.lang.Integer.parseInt (Integer.java:542)
    At java.lang.Short.parseShort (Short.java:118)
    At java.lang.Short.parseShort (Short.java:144)
    At org.jooq.types.UByte.valueOf (UByte.java:101)
    At org.simpleflatmapper.reflect.generated.org.jooq.types.AsmInstantiatorUByteFromStringIntovalue_I1.newInstance (Unknown Source) "


    String openId = "sdjakfh13145sdkadkdfc";
    JdbcMapper<Tuple2<UserRecord, List<CarRecord>>> mapper = JdbcMapperFactory.newInstance().addKeys("id")
            .newMapper(new TypeReference<Tuple2<UserRecord, List<CarRecord>>>() {
            });

ResultSet rs = dslContext.select().from(User.USER).leftJoin(Car.CAR).on(User.USER.ID.eq(Car.CAR.USER_ID)).where(User.USER.OPEN_ID.eq(openId)).fetchResultSet();
    try {Stream<Tuple2<UserRecord, List<CarRecord>>> stream = mapper.stream(rs);
        stream.forEach(System.out::println);
    } catch (MappingException | SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: From your stack trace, this looks like a bug in simpleflatmapper. I see you've already reported an issue there as well: https://github.com/arnaudroger/SimpleFlatMapper/issues/453

Comment: Yes, I suspect that because the data after the query has a null value that causes mapper to fail, I would like to ask how to deal with the relational mapping such as one-two-man in jooq.

Comment: the mapper does not make any assumption on null value handling, I'll add a test and see what can be done. I might add a value check on instantiator with one value. would be activated by default with the jooq mapper, but not for others.

Comment: thx you. Please show me the result of the test.

Comment: hi @Lukas

Map<com.chunfytseng.zyzy.gen.tables.pojos.User, List<com.chunfytseng.zyzy.gen.tables.pojos.Car>> map1 = stream
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(r -> {
     return r.into(com.chunfytseng.zyzy.gen.tables.pojos.User.class);
    }, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.mapping(r -> {
     return r.into(com.chunfytseng.zyzy.gen.tables.pojos.Car.class);
    }, Collectors.toList())));

Map:
userid open_id name carid userid brand
1          abc        a        1       1       x
1          abc        a        2       1       x

I want the result is：

User

Comment: @ChunfyTseng: That's not very readable in a comment :) Would you mind asking a new question as I don't think that's related...

Comment: @Lukas
ok,i see.

Comment: @ChunfyTseng do you have a UByte in the CarRecord object? I'm trying to understand why the mapper would use a UByteFromString, what is the column type for that field? also I released a new version 3.13 which will handle null value for unsigned jooq type, but at the moment not from String as I still don't really understand how it got there.

Comment: @ChunfyTseng I actually reproduced the UByte issue, sfm use the String instantiatior instead of the number one, that a separate issue, version 3.13 should solve the issue you experience with the mapper.